# How to call controller function in view page in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

```
public function getPendingOrder($id) 
{
    $pendingOrder = DB::table('erp_purchase_order_details')->where('product_category_id','=',$id)->where('received','=','0')->count();  

    return $pendingOrder;
}
```

Comment: i want call this function in view page such like  $controller->getPendingOrder(5);

Comment: it's a bad idea, you should read MVC basics.

Comment: then how to use this type of function

Comment: It's best you create a custom class, then you will be able to call its function in view. Or just use Laravel with() method to pass variable to view.

Comment: You shouldn’t. That completely goes against what MVC _is_. Your controller should inject data to your view. Your view is exactly what it’s say on the tin: a _view_. Is should display data only, not fetch it.

Comment: why you are even using MVC ?

Comment: What you should do, in order to follow the MVC pattern - is to move the function to a Model or Service and then pass the result as a variable in all controller or as suggested below - you can use view widgets.

Answer (score 0):

To access controller methods in your laravel project we can create the object for that controller then we can call method of controller using created object

Suppose i have a controller Product and one method getPendingOrders() method inside it:

```
class Product extends BaseController
{
    public static function getPendingOrders($id)
    {
        $pendingOrder = DB::table('erp_purchase_order_details')- >where('product_category_id','=',$id)->where('received','=','0')->count();

        return $pendingOrder;
     }
}
```

So in your view you can call this method using :: 
For example
{{ Product::getPendingOrders(10); }}

Another method is to create object of that class and then call the method if it is not static.

Comment: use following command using your command line 
`php artisan dump autoload`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extra functionally to your laravel project use laravel widget package its work like wordpress shortcodes and you can call them as laravel blade tags

Please read the document carefully

http://sky.pingpong-labs.com/docs/2.0/widget